# Iterating over the big matrix containing 3000 rows and calculate the correlation

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to loop over the a matrix and do the correlation coefficient of each two-row and print out the correlation matrix.

```
ID A B C D E F G H I
Row01 0.08 0.47 0.94 0.33 0.08 0.93 0.72 0.51 0.55
Row02 0.37 0.87 0.72 0.96 0.20 0.55 0.35 0.73 0.44
Row03 0.19 0.71 0.52 0.73 0.03 0.18 0.13 0.13 0.30
Row04 0.08 0.77 0.89 0.12 0.39 0.18 0.74 0.61 0.57
Row05 0.09 0.60 0.73 0.65 0.43 0.21 0.27 0.52 0.60
Row06 0.60 0.54 0.70 0.56 0.49 0.94 0.23 0.80 0.63
Row07 0.02 0.33 0.05 0.90 0.48 0.47 0.51 0.36 0.26
Row08 0.34 0.96 0.37 0.06 0.20 0.14 0.84 0.28 0.47
........
(30000 rows!)
```

I want the Pearson correlation output as:

```
 Row01
Row01 1.000
Row02 0.012
Row03 0.023
Row04 0.820
Row05 0.165
Row06 0.230
Row07 0.376
Row08 0.870
```

output as Row01.txt

```
Row02
Row01 0.012
Row02 1.000
Row03 0.023
Row04 0.820
Row05 0.165
Row06 0.230
Row07 0.376
Row08 0.870
```

output as Row02.txt.
.
.
.
.

output files will be 30000!

I am aware of this algorithm looks stupid, that `matrix<-cor(T(data))` will do the whole thing, and half of the corr matrix is enough as the corr result is symmetric along the diagonal.

But my problems are

1. my data is too big for R to handle 30000x30000.
2. It is hard to retrieve the specific correlations of a specific row with the rest.
3. Using my "stupid algorithm" I can easily get the corr of my interest from the folder.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but something like this should work I guess

**EDIT**: corrected code to avoid huge matrix

```
correl <- NULL
for (i in 1:nrow(datamatrix))
    {
    correl <- apply(datamatrix, 1, function(x){cor(datamatrix[,i], x)})
    write.table(correl, paste("col", i, ".txt", sep="")
    }
```

Comment: Hm I fear that doesn't fly. Original Poster claimed `datamatrix` was too big for memory.

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel: hmmm that's true, I assumed he was talking about the output matrix, but the input matrix is huge too... didn't think about that. wasn't there a package to handle huge matrices in memory or am I wrong?

Comment: Thanks! I had problem with my SUSE where I want to use. I will try the code and get back soon.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Nico!
Almost got there after I corrected small bugs. Here I attach my script:

```
datamatrix=read.table("ref.txt",sep="\t",header=T,row.names=1)
correl <- NULL
for (i in 1:nrow(datamatrix)) {
  correl <- apply(datamatrix, 1, function(x){cor(t(datamatrix[,i]))})
  write.table(correl, paste(row.names(datamatrix)[i], ".txt", sep=""))
}
```

But I am afraid the function(x) part is of problem, that seems to be `t(datamatrix[i,j])`, which will calculate corr of any two rows.

Actually I need to iterate through the matrix.
first `cor(row01, row02)` get one correlation between rwo01 and row02; then `cor(row01, row03)` to get the correlation of row01 and rwo03, ....and till correlation between row01 row30000.Now I got the first column for

```
      row01
Row01 **1.000**
Row02 0.012
Row03 0.023
Row04 0.820
Row05 0.165
Row06 0.230
Row07 0.376
Row08 0.870
```

and save it to file row01.txt;

Similarly get

```
      Row02
Row01 0.012
Row02 **1.000**
Row03 0.023
Row04 0.820
Row05 0.165
Row06 0.230
Row07 0.376
Row08 0.870
```

and save it to file row02.txt.

Totally I will get 30000 files. It is stupid, but this can skip the memory limit and can be easily handled for the correlation of a specific row.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at the `bigmemory` package and the `foreach` package, to do these calculations in large memory mapped files (i.e. input matrix is one file, correlation matrix is another).  This way you can make use of multiple cores and not store much in RAM.